# Object Field History Empty Date and User Field

Tags: field-history

Hey so I haven't any documentations on this.

I'm seeing this in the Field History list
[image]

The highlighted line doesn't have a date or a user. I was thinking this is because it's the same as the record above it but I haven't seen any documentation on it. Am I right or is there something more to this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is correct, if you run a report on this record though you will see the user and date for the change, this is only in the related list view that the items are grouped together.